# Selenium python script in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, selenium

I am facing the following error, while running the python script with Selenium.  Kindly help me to solve this.

```
(Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\WaheGuru\workspace\test\new\first.py", line 8, in <module>     
from selenium.common.keys import Keys ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 
'selenium.common.keys')
```

Comment: Is selenium installed on your system?  What happens if you try just `import selenium`?

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have Python and selenium installed... then something like this should work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def someCode():
#Some Code to do something with some URL
    elem = driver.find_element_by_name("<Some_Elem_With_Input>")
    elem.send_keys("FOO")
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

if selenium is not installed then run the following command

```
pip install selenium
```

Check out http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html